# Convert a list of long ip to dotted ip

Tags: bash, ip, long-integer

I have a list of long ip format and i want to convert it to dotted format
Do some research and found here this great bash

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f
# dec2ip
BEGIN {
    dec = ARGV[1]
    for (e = 3; e >= 0; e--) {
        octet = int(dec / (256 ^ e))
        dec -= octet * 256 ^ e
        ip = ip delim octet
        delim = "."
    }
    printf("%s\n", ip)
}
```

But it convert one by one
Please how to make it open file and convert all ip then print result into text file
Best regards

Comment: That's not `bash`; it's `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lnwe '$, = "."; print unpack "C*", pack "N", $_' < input-file
```

`$,` sets the separator. the `N` template of [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack) turns a string like 2130706433 into a sequence of bytes (`7f 00 00 01`), and the `C*` template of [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) changes it into a list of corresponding numbers.

Comment: @ChametLeont: Just accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The given `awk` snippet assumes it will be called once. You can adapt it to process each line of an input file.

```
awk '{ dec=$0;
       delim="";
       for (e = 3; e >= 0; e--) {
           octet = int(dec / (256 ^ e));
           dec -= octet * 256 ^ e;
           ip = ip delim octet;
           delim = ".";
       }'
       printf("%s\n", ip)}' list_of_integer_ip_addresses.txt
```